# Determine which condition caused an if statement to execute

Tags: java

So I have an if statement that looks like the following:

```
List<Integer> portsInUse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
. . .
if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort1) 
        || portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort2){

    fail(_____, "This port is already in use.");
}
```

`newPort1` and `newPort2` are assigned by digging them out of an HttpServletRequest.  `fail(String parameter, String message)` is an internal method to alert the user that something went wrong.

What I'd like to do is be able to tell which condition caused the if statement to trigger, and then set the failure message accordingly.  Can I do that, or would I have to do something like this:

```
List<Integer> portsInUse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
. . .
boolean port1 = portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort1);
boolean port2 = portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort2);
if(port1 || port2){
    if(port1)
        fail("newPort1", "This port is already in use.");
    else
        fail("newPort2", "This port is already in use.");
}
```

Or, third option, should I break up the conditions like this:

```
List<Integer> portsInUse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
. . .
if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort1) {
    fail("newPort1", "This port is already in use.");
}
if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort2) {
    fail("newPort2", "This port is already in use.");
}
```

I'm sure I'm overcomplicating things, but thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to separate the conditions out as you have done.

Comment: Is it possible that both ports can be in use? If yes, what should it do? You need to decide that first.

Comment: MRAB: yes, definitely.  When both ports are in use, it should fail for both ports.  It looks like option 3 is the closest to what I need.

Comment: Is this limited to only 2 ports, or could there be more?

Comment: Just the two ports for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to determine which specific port is in use, the third option would be more ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Fourth option...

```
List<Integer> portsInUse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
. . .
if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort1) {
    fail("newPort1", "This port is already in use.");
}
else if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort2) {
    fail("newPort2", "This port is already in use.");
}else{
    //No ports in use
}
```

Fifth option...

```
List<Integer> portsInUse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
. . .
if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort1) {
    if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort2) {
        //both ports in use
    }else{
        //port 1 in use
    }
}
else if(portsInUse.contains((Integer) newPort2) {
    //Port 2 in use
}else{
    //No ports in use
}
```

Comment: That looks a lot like Option 3... I'm unsure I want to go with it because there are occasions I can see where both ports are already in use.

Comment: Posted a fifth option just for fun...
It all depends on what you need accomplished.  Any option is acceptable

Comment: If there was more going on when I had both ports in use, I'd probably go with that new option.  Thanks though.

Comment: No worries at all!  As I said, it all comes down to what you find most readable, and what fits the best for your specific situation.  I'm simply providing alternatives for anybody who might see this in the future.  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think your third option, is the best because you avoid the extra conditional of option2 `if(port1 || port2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> portsInUse = new ArrayList<Integer>();
. . .
List<Integer> portsToCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();

portsToCheck.add(newPort1);
portsToCheck.add(newPort2);
...    

for (Integer port: portsToCheck){
    if (portsInUse.contains(port)) {
        fail(port+"", "This port is already in use.");  
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the thought, but it seems a little more complicated than some of the other options.

Comment: code is shorter and cleaner, besides, you don't have to add another condition should a third new port come into existence.

Comment: besides if you receive the list of newPorts as a parameter, you don't have to ever touch this code again. The original code is hard-coded to work with exactly two newPorts.